# images is not showing up in under maintenance page

Tags: html, iis, webserver

I added an under maintenance page in my site.  In that page, I just put one image and message.  The image is inside images folder.  But the image is not showing up in under maintenance page when the site is under maintenance mode.  If not under maintenance mode, the image is shown in that page. I don't know how to solve it.

In my page, the code is simple as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0    Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Under Maintenance</title>
</head>
<body style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;">
    <div>
        <img src="images/under_maintenance.gif" alt="Under Maintenance" />
        <h2>This site is currently</h2>
        <h1>UNDER MAINTENANCE</h1>
        <h3>We will be back shortly</h3> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your code is perfect may be problem is in your image or path can u provide under_maintenance.gif ? ...

Comment: Yes, the page cannot find image path in maintenance mode.  Normally, the path is correct for other pages.

Comment: Does changing this `src="/images/under_maintenance.gif"` help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting your website into maintenance mode probably blocks access to everything, including the image you're trying to display. Either white-list the image (how you do depends on what server you're running) or host the image on an external image host like [imgur](http://imgur.com/).

Comment: Hi Marchel, I use IIS.  Where must my image be host internally? And how to define that path? I don't want to host the image on an external image host.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both for answering my question. :) 
Finally, I can solve it.
I embed the image as base64 format like

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhIQE6AfcAA..." alt="Under Maintenance" />.
```

Answer (score 0):

Not working in IE for me with base64 but good point.

I use MVC and maintenance mode with App_Offline.htm . There I have base64 string as img src.

Firefox, Chrome, Opera show image. IE8 not.

Comment: this should be a comment, as it does not answer the question